# i want to query letters and add them as numbers in php how can I do that?

Tags: php

Hellow everyone, I have just post some subjects grades like MATH= A, PHY= B ENG= C and those letters have values like A=1, B=2 C=3 into my database `enter code here`and I want to query them and add them as numbers. how can I do that?
NOTE: I dont want to post the direct numbers I want to post the grades 
Thsnks very much in advance
Example:
from the codes below student scored C in MATH, B in KISW , D in HIST C in GEO e.t.c and the value of A=1, B=2 C=3 and D=4

```
    <?php
    include('connection.php');


    @$id=$_GET['id']
    $query1=mysql_query("select * from results WHERE id='$id'  ");
    $query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1);
    $id=$query2['id'];


    $b=$query2['math'];
    $c=$query2['kisw'];
    $d=$query2['hist'];
    $e=$query2['geo'];
    $f=$query2['eng'];

    $h=$query2['civ'];

    $k=$query2['bio'];


    ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tour to read about how to ask a valuable, answerable question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you want, but try this. This will convert the letter to its corresponding number

```
<?php
    function Converter($letter) {
    switch($letter) {
        case 'A':
            return 1;
            break;
        case 'B':
            return 2;
            break;
        case 'C':
            return 3;
            break;
        case 'D':
            return 4;
            break;
        default:
            echo "LETTER NOT FOUND";
    }
}
    echo Converter($b);
    // Display 3, because Math == C
?>
```

Comment: Thanks very much boss that's exactly what I was looking for. remain blessed always. @CarlJan